# How to read the list of number in c

Tags: c, file, pointers

I have a file which includes product name, product quantity and product price in the following format.

```
file.txt

3
Product   Qty  Price
Tv        2    10
Mobile    3    20
Computer  5    30
```

I want to read the number of products from the integer (such as 3) given above the product list and count the total price of the products. The program will use struct to read the product details such as

```
struct product {         
    Char name[30];
    int qty ;
    float price;        
}
```

What are the best practices to make this program easier?

Comment: Try using `fgets()` to fetch lines of input, and `sscanf()` to parse the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try if the following program can help you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct product {
    char name[30];
    int qty;
    float price;
};

int main(void) {
    int count = 0;
    char line[100];
    FILE *fptr;
    fptr = fopen("file.txt", "r");
    fscanf(fptr, "%d", &count); // count = 3
    struct product *p = malloc(sizeof(struct product));
    int i = 0;
    double sum = 0;
    while (i < count + 2 && fgets(line, sizeof(line), fptr) != NULL) {
        if (i > 1) {
            sscanf(line, "%s %d %f\n", (*p).name, &(*p).qty, &(*p).price);
            sum = sum + (*p).price;
        }
        i++;
    }
    printf("sum: %f\n", sum);
    free(p);
    return 0;
}
```

Test

```
$ gcc main.c                                                                   
$ ./a.out                                                                      
sum: 60.000000
$
```

Comment: Thank you very much